# freeswitch stream remote audio file

Tags: google-cloud-storage, freeswitch

i'm saving the remote audio files on google cloud storage.
i want to play these files in freeswitch.

when i use:

```
mediaLink = "http://storage.googleapis.com/myBucket/file.wav";
session:streamFile(mediaLink);
```

it works great.

But when i use signed urls

```
mediaLink = "http://storage.googleapis.com/myBucket/file.wav?GoogleAccessId=xxx-xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1408903962590&Signature=xxb%2Fx%2FDfGJlrUuz0%2F6kA6ormmReW6oN%2F0xxy3%2BwWxXc%3D";
session:streamFile(mediaLink);
```

i get this error:

```
2014-08-24 20:42:48.770818 [ERR] mod_httapi.c:2696 File at url [http://storage.googleapis.com/myBucket/file.wav?GoogleAccessId=xxx-xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1408903962590&Signature=xxb%2Fx%2FDfGJlrUuz0%2F6kA6ormmReW6oN%2F0xxy3%2BwWxXc%3D] is unreachable!
```

Thanks,
Snabel

Comment: If you paste the signed URL into a web browser, do you see an error? Can you paste that error here?

Comment: that's the issue, the signed URL is working on the browser. i can download the file via the browser. so i know the link is valid.

Comment: i tried removing each parameter to see which one is causing the error.
when i removed this parameter:

GoogleAccessId=xxx-xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com
freeswitch was able do download and play the file. are there characters in this parameter which are causing session:streamFile() failure?
should i escape some characters? if so which and how?

this parameter is mandatory so i can't just remove it from the link. any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: URL encoding solved this error, URLEncoder.encode(url_params, "UTF-8"); to encode the URL parameters.
The url i got:
URL = http://storage.googleapis.com/myBucket/file.wav?
GoogleAccessId%3D703391026438d3tc85gd1jiu6f32mckumln3b2gc5qhk%40developer.gserviceaccount.com%26
Expires%3D1408970638639%26
Signature%3DF3zM%2Fkr2mKqulgrdp1F6Q9Gdf5rKvy7GHrWOW5GMU
xxxxxxxxxxxXxxxxxxXXXXXXXXjXtFFRBJp4a%2BfhrQJcrs4p%2FZhsSdB
kyet8qVwf%2BRUN8I0ROA%2FNpJ%2B0T0eEBqP2PNFPHzI8GKQWm7wI6mmZDwKtgUT3A%2BVXGV74nUqHrNY%3D
But now i get this exception: [ERR] mod_httapi.c:2723 Error checking file cache (check permissions)

Comment: I know this is a bit old, but this may be related to how freeswitch deals with the HTTP request. This problem also had occurred with Amazon S3 as per this [post](http://freeswitch-users.2379917.n2.nabble.com/mod-httapi-problem-when-trying-to-play-an-audio-hosted-in-S3-amazon-cloud-td7583406.html). There's a proposed workaround there involving a patch to do a GET instead of a HEAD but no information if this worked (it seems there is something funky with the way S3 and presumably GCS handles cache-control).

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get this to work with `playback` from `mod_dptools` and `mod_shout` (for `mp3` support) on FreeSWITCH 1.10. The [Google Storage signing algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) is also at V4 at the moment.

Testing workflow:

1. ```
   $ gsutil signurl -r us service-account.json gs://the-bucket/a-song.mp3

   URL
   gs://the-bucket/a-song.mp3

   HTTP Method
   GET

   Expiration
   2019-08-24 19:03:02

   Signed URL
   https://storage.googleapis.com/the-bucket/a-song.mp3?x-goog-signature=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&x-goog-algorithm=GOOG4-RSA-SHA256&x-goog-credential=name-of-the-service-account%2F20190824%2Fus%2Fstorage%2Fgoog4_request&x-goog-date=20190824T183009Z&x-goog-expires=3600&x-goog-signedheaders=host
   ```
2. Using `playback` with the [FreeSWITCH Lua API's `IVRMenu`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+API+Reference#LuaAPIReference-freeswitch.IVRMenu) ([examples](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+IVR+Menu+Example)) (here's the [full application code](https://github.com/access-news/phone-service/blob/b73220a21cc034ea929646632220ce618ef73b07/freeswitch/scripts/ivr.lua)):

   ```
   -- signed URL above stripped of the URL scheme
   local signed_url_without_url_scheme = "storage.googleapis..."

   i.unregistered_main:bindAction(
     "menu-exec-app",
     "playback shout://" .. signed_url_without_url_scheme, 
     "3"
   )
   ```

---

I had no luck with `streamFile`, but not because of the signed URLs, but because I couldn't even get it to work. The documentation is very spotty, and certain sections even contradict each other (compare [`mod_shout`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/mod_shout) and [`session:streamFile`](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Lua+API+Reference#LuaAPIReference-session:streamFile) for example).